# Darling binaries

Tags: software-installation, executable, binary

Where can I find pre-built binaries for [darling](https://www.darlinghq.org/)? I do not want to have to build from source.

This is not a duplicate, because other answers don't give binaries, they just show how to compile from source.

Comment: @N0rbert I don't see any binaries there...